# Scrollbars with zoom in and out on XAML canvas

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, scrollbar, zooming

I have a canvas that will be having images generated from code behind and the my xaml looks like below

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
    <WrapPanel >
        <Grid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Menu x:Name="menu1" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" DockPanel.Dock="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.48,3.04" >
                <MenuItem Header="_File" Width="92" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Century Gothic" >

                    <MenuItem Header="_Print"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Print Preview"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>

                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            <ToolBar x:Name="toolBar1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderBrush="Red"  BorderThickness="3" Margin="0,0,0,900"   Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
                <Button x:Name="Zoomin" Click="menuItemZoomin_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1" Width="90"  FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="55" RenderTransformOrigin ="0.917,0.587" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsEnabled="True" FontFamily="Century Gothic" Content="Zoom In" />
                <Button x:Name="Zoomout" Click="menuItemZoomout_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1" Width="90" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.917,0.587" Height="55" FontFamily="Century Gothic" Content="Zoom Out"/>
                <!--<Button x:Name="Print" Click="PrintBtn_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1" Width="90" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.917,0.587" Height="55" FontFamily="Century Gothic" Content="Print"/>-->
            </ToolBar>



            <Canvas x:Name="cvsWarehouse"  Grid.Row="1"  Focusable="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"    MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="15,144,122,151" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name ="st1" ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=uiScaleSlider}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=uiScaleSlider}"  />
                        <TranslateTransform Y="100" />
                    </TransformGroup>

                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </WrapPanel>
```

**cvsWarehouse** is the actual canvas where lot of code behind works goes on in generating the images and the output window looks like below.
[image: Scrollbar showing only half]

When it is maximized it doesn't show the scroll bars. I have googled like crazy and tried everything I can but still could not solve the issue. I want to scroll till end of the canvas. There are more images below also but **wrappanel or Layout transform** nothing worked here. This also have zoom in and out but still it won't show me scrollbars.

[image: Maximized but still content is there below but no scrollbars]
Here is what I mean when I say content is still there below

[image: Such a huge canvas]

How to make this scrollbar visible through out. Like zoom in or out or minimized or maximized

Comment: wow... Now I see XAML is really pain in the neck. I don't see anyone having a solution for this problem. It is all over the internet but no proper solution yet.

Comment: Really... still no solution. WPF is really screwing me up

Comment: Can someone please look at the issue? I am looking for a fix for this not points for the question. Please try to understand. Its been a week and nothing has moved with this issue

Comment: Come on... Can someone please help me fixing this bug in WPF

Comment: Could you please check this bug @Kelly Barnard

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found the first answer for this question to be helpful -( [LayoutTransform on certain elements in canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819890/layouttransform-on-certain-elements-in-canvas)).  Apply the ScrollViewer to your canvas (the element on which Layout transform has been applied). The change in size of the canvas has to be detected by the scrollviewer for the scroll bar to appear. Also, I don't think you need these inside the Canvas tag - ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible". These definitions present inside the ScrollViewer tag should render the desired functionality.